# ExpressJS Routing with Two MongoDB Collections Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, routes

I currently have a collection modeled that displays all of the documents that match a query of two properties within my model. These two properties are displayed within my url path and a resulting route is triggered by grabbing the two properties from the route and displaying documents that match those values. e.x. color: 'red', day:'monday', if a URL is displayed with /red/monday, then all of the documents (images) with those values are displayed. My current route performs this query correctly.

I now want to create a second collection that contains the descriptions for each of the possible combinations of 'color' and 'day'. Basically when I go to /red/monday, the images are displayed and then a description also appears.

I'm not sure the best way to join these two combinations within one query within a route. Any help?

Images model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    day: { type: String, enum: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'] },
    color: { type: String, enum: ['Black', 'Blue', 'White'] },
    imageName: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    imageSource: String
});

var Images = mongoose.model('Images', imageSchema);

module.exports = Images;
```

Descriptions model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var descriptionSchema = new Schema({
    pattern: { type: String, enum: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'] },
    color: { type: String, enum: ['Black', 'Blue', 'White'] },
    body: String,
});

var Description = mongoose.model('Description', descriptionSchema);

module.exports = Description;
```

Current Routing:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var Images = require('./models/imagesModel');
var Description = require('./models/descriptionModel');

    /*==== Color Pages  ====*/

    router.get('/:color/day-selection', function(req, res){

        console.log(req.params.color);

        res.render('pages/color.hbs', {
            color: req.params.pattern
        });
    });


    /*====  Results ====*/


    router.get('/:color/:day/result', function(req, res){

        console.log(req.params.color);

        Images.find( { pattern: req.params.color, color: req.params.day }, function(err, image){
            if (err) { console.log(err); }
            console.log(image);

            res.render('pages/result.hbs', {
                color   : req.params.color,
                day : req.params.day,
                image : image
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to make the urls a bit more RESTful.

Url to get all colors for a day would be something like

`route.get(':days')` => serves GET `/mondays` -> get a list of all colors for monday.

`route.get('/days')` => serves GET `/days` -> get a list of all days

`route.get(':days/:colors')` => serves GET `/mondays/reds` -> get description of red for monday.

`route.get(':day/:color/images')` => servers GET `/mondays/reds/images` -> get all images for `/mondays/reds/images`

`route.get(':days/:colors/images/:id')` => serves GET `:days/:colors/images/:id` => serves GET on `/mondays/reds/images/mongo-db-id` -> get that specific image

Couple of other changes,

1. Move the service layer code out of routers and inject them into the instance of `express()`. Example, read shameless plug, -  https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap/app.js#L86
2. Pass db connections as params to the service layers. https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap/blob/master/core/index.js
3. (Optional) - Use promises and generators for flow control. Ex - https://gist.github.com/swarajgiri/16202e32aa4d80d45c62

Comment: thanks for all of the tips. Can you elaborate on the first of the other changes you mentioned? Moving the service layer code out of the routers?

Comment: Cphill - take a look at the linked github repo. What it basically does is create separate modules that handle creation and persisting entities and inject them into the app. Let me know if you have any more questions.